# How to enable RemoteFX for a Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remotefx

I wanted to take advantage of the new "RemoteFX" feature. However, all the blogs are talking about having a Windows 2008R2 Server with SP1 and running a virtual macihne with RemoteFX.

In my case, I have two machines with Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. And I want to connect to my desktop machine, from my laptop. With RemoteFX.

How can I do that?

Comment: (After connecting to the host machine, I have the Aero interface, but I just can't start any game, or 3D application.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2012/11/26/remotefx-features-for-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012/, you should be able to access rich content on Windows 7 Enterprise if you install the RDP 8.0 content update.

Comment: It would be nice to include how to upgrade to the latest RDP in the answer

Comment: There is only one other answer (never the less, I clarified). The blog post linked within contains a direct link to how to install the client update.

Comment: I have Windows 7 Ultimate, and RDP 8.1 is supported, but I see no options for RemoteFX on it. I assume I also need Windows Server?

Comment: Broken link....

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. RemoteFX was designed and built for servers hosting virtualized desktops. When Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 was released it contained an updated client that supports RemoteFX, however the host still needs to be a Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server.

Comment: So if I want to play a game through LAN (on my laptop), I have to install Server 2008R2 on my desktop PC. AND install a Windows 7 guest ON the server, which will run the games. Right?

Comment: It has to be a Hyper-V server, so a Windows 7 SP 1 VM on the server. Plus there are hardware requirements for the server to use RemoteFX. This is not really designed for gaming, so YMMV (Your mileage may vary) on what works and what doesn't. For the technical details, check out this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817586(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Why would this not be natively supported... Just making people jump through absurd hoops.