# Remote desktop (remmina) to Altium PCB does not work

Tags: windows-7, linux, remote-desktop, arch-linux, directx

In my basic setup, I have two machines:

1. Desktop workstation running [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) with [Remmina](https://www.remmina.org/wp/) installed, it works.
2. Laptop workstation running [Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) running [Altium version 16.0](http://www.altium.com/)

I am working remotely with `Altium` via [RDP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) from desktop workstation running `Linux` and `Remmina` and **schematic design** is working perfectly. However, if I try to **switch Altium into PCB mode**, I get following error in `Windows` (if I switch Altium into PCB mode directly on laptop workstation, without RDP, I can design PCB flawlessly), I get following `DirectX 9.0 is not suppoerted error`:
[image: Direct X Error]
Does anyone has any clue how to get rid of this nasty error?

Comment: Don't expect to get 3D applications to function well (or at all) over RDP. It seems you might need a minimum of Windows 7 Enterprise on the machine you are RDP-ing into: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b6027038-1a60-4442-953a-b7a160d0573e/enabling-directx-for-rdc?forum=winRDc

Comment: @Mokubai I have Windows 7 Ultimate, which is flagship version.

Comment: It might be "flagship" but it is not the Enterprise edition.

Comment: The feature required for DirectX to work over RDP is RemoteFX and is only enabled on Enterprise editions it seems: https://superuser.com/questions/385238/how-to-enable-remotefx-for-a-windows-7-machine

Comment: You might be able to get it to run using one of the game streaming solutions, such as Nvidia Gamestream, or Steam In-home Streaming, but I would expect the latency to be quite bad over the internet.